# Data Failing to Transfer from File to Integer Array

Tags: java, file, matrix, filereader

So I'm really not sure how to put this to words. I'm having trouble transferring the data from a file my program has created back into the program for manipulation.

The program creates a .sp file consisting of 81 values 0-9. Here's what the file I'm using looks like:

```
000030640020698170085700003007010000090503060000060700800007290012489050054020000
```

The code I'm using to pull these values from the file to an integer array is:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("~/Documents"));
        int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            FileReader fr = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = textReader.readLine();

            int pos = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                    System.out.println("Putting " + line.charAt(pos) + " in (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
                    puzzle[i][j] = line.charAt(pos);
                    pos++;
                }
```

`line` prints out as:

```
000030640020698170085700003007010000090503060000060700800007290012489050054020000
```

I'm even getting output that makes sense...

```
Putting 0 in (0, 0)
Putting 0 in (0, 1)
Putting 0 in (0, 2)
Putting 0 in (0, 3)
Putting 3 in (0, 4)
Putting 0 in (0, 5)
Putting 6 in (0, 6)
Putting 4 in (0, 7)
Putting 0 in (0, 8)
Putting 0 in (1, 0)
```

However, when I view the newly created matrix, I get:

```
48 48 48 48 51 48 54 52 48 
48 50 48 54 57 56 49 55 48 
48 56 53 55 48 48 48 48 51 
48 48 55 48 49 48 48 48 48 
48 57 48 53 48 51 48 54 48 
48 48 48 48 54 48 55 48 48 
56 48 48 48 48 55 50 57 48 
48 49 50 52 56 57 48 53 48 
48 53 52 48 50 48 48 48 48
```

Why is this happening? I don't see any errors, and the debugging sysout seems to prove it. Is the data somehow becoming corrupted?

Comment: What does `line` output as?

Comment: @Tdorno Added the output of `line`.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

```
puzzle[i][j] = line.charAt(pos);
```

`charAt` returns a `char`, not an `int`. When you store the char at a position in your array, the Unicode code point of the character is stored, and not the integer value that you expect.

This can be easily solved by using the `Character` class's `getNumericValue` method:

```
puzzle[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(pos));
```

Comment: ***facedesk***
--
Thanks.